# Why is Access Token null?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplify-auth-cognito

I am using Amplify Auth to sign in a user in my Java android application.

After a couple of times of starting the android emulator, Amplify Auth signs out the user. Upon trying to login again, the user is faced with the error message:

> InvalidParameterException{message=One or more parameters are
> incorrect., cause=InvalidParameterException(message=1 validation error
> detected: Value at 'accessToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member
> must not be null), recoverySuggestion=Enter correct parameters.}
> at
> com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.CognitoAuthExceptionConverter$Companion.lookup(CognitoAuthExceptionConverter.kt:70)

The only way I can work around this is by performing a "wipe data" on the android emulator and re-installing the app.

I don't know how to fix this issue correctly. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps the token simply expired? Update your logic so that a new token is obtained if that happens.

Comment: How do I do this? I have been searching everywhere in Amplify Auth AWS documentation but I can't find an example